# check dataset column values present in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have one dataset with data from database in which primary column is ID. Also I am displaying data from database table in gridview. Now I want to check if all dataset IDs are present in gridview displayed.

For eg.
my dataset is:

```
ID Name
1  abc
2  xyz
3  qwe
```

Gridview displayed as:

```
ID Name
1  abc
2  xyz
3  qwe
4  ghg
5  hfj
6  ert
```

How to check dataset IDs are present in gridview and if all the IDs are present in gridview, display a success message?

Please help me with code demo or code samples if you have.

Comment: What is the `DataSource` of the `GridView`? You should compare with that. If that's also a `DataSet`/`DataTable` it's easy: `bool allIdsContained = !ds1.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(r=>r.Field<int>("ID")).Except(ds2.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(r=>r.Field<int>("ID"))).Any()`

Comment: gridview datasource is dataset. can i get code demo in simple c#

Comment: It's C# ..Man. Just copy the code to editor..:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OPerate on the Dataset which you are binding to the Gridview 
Example -

```
//DataSet SourceDataSet ;
//DataSet CompareDataSet ; 
foreach(DataRow dr in CompareDataSet.Tables[0].Rows){
    if(!SourceDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Contains(dr["Id"])){
          return false; // if source does not contain id return false
    }
}
return true;
```

Hope You understand now how to do that.

Create ID column as Primary key in sourceDataset as

```
SourceDataSet.Tables[0].PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] {SourceDataSet.Tables[0].Columns["Id"]};
```

Comment: thanks for helping..

Comment: If your problem solved please accept it as answer thanks

Comment: it gives following error:- 'System.Data.DataColumn' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Contains<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, TSource)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: I have Updated the Answer in the If condition inside loop instead of Columns.Contains try Rows.Contains as given in the answer

Comment: Following error occured:- Table doesn't have a primary key.

Comment: Contains Method only works on primary key dows ID is not the Primary of the Datatable ?

Comment: if making Id as primary key not creating any problem i refer you to create a primary key as find() and contains() method only works if there is atleast one primary key in the table.

Comment: how do I set the primary key for datatable?

Comment: I have Edited my code with sample of how to make id as primary key of table please look at it

Comment: @Krupesh03 Had Your problem solved if yes Please Accept it as answer Thanks

Comment: It's working. Thanks a lot